# scanf can't scan into uint8_t

Tags: c

When I try to use `scanf` with `uint8_t`, I get crazy results.
Using `int`, I get the expected output "08 - 15".
Using `uint8_t`, I get "00 - 15".

```
const char *foo = "0815";
uint8_t d1, d2; // output: 00 - 15 (!!!)
// int d1, d2;         // output: 08 - 15
sscanf(foo, "%2d %2d", &d1, &d2);
printf("%02d - %02d\n", d1, d2);
```

I'm using GCC.

Comment: Use `sscanf(foo, "%hhd %hhd", &d1, &d2);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `%d` is wrong, because it means you are passing `int *` but you actually want to pass `uint8_t *`.  You will need to use the appropriate macro:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
sscanf(foo, "%2" SCNu8 " %2" SCNu8, &d1, &d2);
```

Most compilers should be giving you warnings about your version of the code.  Here is Clang's output:

```
test2.c:8:24: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
      'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wformat]
sscanf(foo, "%2d %2d", &d1, &d2);
             ~~~       ^~~
             %2s
test2.c:8:29: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
      'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wformat]
sscanf(foo, "%2d %2d", &d1, &d2);
                 ~~~        ^~~
                 %2s
2 warnings generated.
```

For `uint8_t`, this does not apply to `printf()`, since the `uint8_t` will always be promoted to `int` before it is passed to `printf()`.

Comment: @wallyk: Feel free to correct typos by clicking the "edit" button.

Comment: Sure, but since the rest of the code was not completely familiar, I wasn't sure if it was some new compiler feature.

Comment: On the last point, not necessarily. Depending on the implementation of both `printf` and `va_args`, it may "just work", or may fail.

Comment: @slugonamission: No, the C standard explicitly mandates that integer types with less range than `int` get promoted to `int` when passed to variadic functions.  The `uint8_t` type's range is also guaranteed to be a subset of the range for `int`, so this is guaranteed to always be correct.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - whoops, I need to re-check a bug I ran into a while back then. It's been a while, but I recall getting strange behaviour when accidentally mis-specifying format specifiers. Cheers :)

Comment: @slugonamission: For reference, it's called the *default argument promotions* and §6.5.2.2 ¶6,7 of n1570 define them and say that they apply to variadics.  §6.3.1.1 ¶2 defines integer promotions.  You can also peek in `<inttypes.h>` and note that `PRIi8` is the exact same as `PRIi32`.

Comment: @Dill: Yes, it does look ugly.  The alternative is to use `unsigned char` and trust that `unsigned char` is always an 8-bit number.  This is a pretty good assumption for most people.

Comment: @DietrichEpp If `uint8_t` exists, it must be a typedef for `unsigned char` (or, pathologically, for a type with the same size and representation as `unsigned char`.) It's not possible to have smaller types than `char`, since `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was thinking of systems where `uint8_t` doesn't exist, e.g., `CHAR_BIT == 32` or something.  You can always `static int check[CHAR_BIT == 8 ? 1 : -1];` to verify, though.

Comment: @DietrichEpp on those systems, the line `uint8_t d1, d2; ` would fail to compile.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Right, but if you switch to `unsigned char`, it compiles but the behavior might be wrong.  Hence the warning, "this is a pretty good assumption for most people".

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were suggesting the use of `%hhu` with `uint8_t` to avoid the "ugliness" of the fixed-width specifier macros.

Comment: @M.M actually, [`SCNu8` is almost always `#define`d as `%hhu`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__inttypes.html) - so, unless you're using some insanely rare platform, I'd say the difference ain't big - mostly because *you shouldn't use `scanf` anyway*...

Answer (score 6):

The scanf format specifier `%d` says "I promise to give you an `int *`". You break that promise by not supplying the address of an `int`. All bets are off. (It's *undefined behaviour*.)

Moral: Don't lie to your compiler.

Comment: This answer does not help in any way. If someone made such (quite basic) mistake like this, you need to explain why and explain why or why probably shouldn't you use uint8_t for scanf

Answer (score 2):

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1 //or gcc prog.c -std=c99 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(){
    const char *foo = "0815";
    uint8_t d1, d2;
    sscanf(foo, "%2" SCNu8 "%2" SCNu8, &d1, &d2);
    printf("%02" PRIu8 " - %02" PRIu8 "\n", d1, d2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you are telling scanf() to expect a pointer to a 4 byte type (int) when uint8_t is only one byte.

Answer (score 0):

int and uint8_t are different data types
`int` is a 4-bytes signed type, the range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
`uint8_t` is an 1-byte unsigned type, the rang is 0 to 255

if you try to use %d, the error will be something like
`format '%d' expects argument of type 'int*', but argument 4 has type 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} [-Wformat=]`