# variable is losing its value in c program

Tags: c, integer, scanf

This is written in 'c' and compiled with gcc.  I'm not sure what else you need to know.

The smallest complete example I could put together is shown here.  The variable 'numatoms' loses its value when it gets to line 23 (after the scanf()).

I'm stumped. Maybe it has something to do with scanf() overwritting the space for numatoms?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
uint8_t numatoms;
uint8_t r;
char a[20];

do {
    printf("NO. OF ATOMS?");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &numatoms);
    printf("\r\n");
    for(;;){
        printf("value of numatoms is %u\r\n", numatoms);
        printf("RAY?");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%u", &r);
        printf("value of numatoms is %u\r\n", numatoms);
        if(r < 1)
            break;
        else {
            printf("value of numatoms is %u\r\n", numatoms);
        }
    }
    printf("CARE TO TRY AGAIN?");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", a); 
    printf("\r\n");           
} while (a[0] == 'y' || a[0] == 'Y');

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It isn't?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &numatoms);` --> `scanf("%" SCNu8, &numatoms);` (`<inttypes.h>`)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level by 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: when outputting a prompt to the user, there is no need to flush stdout.  the act of calling an input function `scanf()` will cause the prompt to be displayed.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11`  I also use: `-Wconversion` )

Comment: when the `main()` function parameters will not be used, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the variable `numatoms` is declared as `unsigned char` but the "%d" in the `scanf()` function is expecting a 'int', so will corrupt the bytes following the variable `numatoms`  Similar considerations for variable `r`.  the declarations allow a range of input values from 0...255.  Strongly suggest changing those declarations from `uint8_t` to `unsigned int` and using "%u" in the scanf() format strings

Comment: regarding this statement: `scanf("%s", a);`  1) always check the returned value 2) only need a single char, not a string. 3) use `tolower()` from header file: `stype.h` to set the value input to lower case, then only one expression needed in the `while()` statement. 4) when using the input/format specifier '%s', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is only less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow (I.E. undefined behavior) which can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when prompting the user for input, always tell the user the range limits.  The array 'a[]' is not a meaningful name.  variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Suggest `char choice;` and use '%c' in the scanf() statement (or better call `getchar()`

Comment: Thanks for all the great information. Truly above and beyond.  In my defense about the variable names such as 'a' and 'r', this is a reproduction of one of the first programs I was exposed to.  It is called "Blackbox" by Jeff Kenton of Creative Computing 1978. In My attempt at conversion from Microsoft BASIC to C I wanted to preserve the original "feel" and integrity of his work.  I changed 'numatoms' back to 'n' when I finished.  Thanks again to you guys  and thanks to Jeff and Creative Computing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use macros for format specifiers for integer types defined in the header `<inttypes.h>`.

From the C Standard (7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers)

> 1 Each of the following object-like macros expands to a character
>   string literal containing a conversion specifier, possibly modified by
>   a length modifier, suitable for use within the format argument of a
>   formatted input/output function when converting the corresponding
>   integer type. These macro names have the general form of PRI
>   (character string literals for the fprintf and fwprintf family) or SCN
>   (character string literals for the fscanf and fwscanf family),217)
>   followed by the conversion specifier, followed by a name corresponding
>   to a similar type name in 7.20.1. In these names, N represents the
>   width of the type as described in 7.20.1.

The general form of the macro used for unsigned integer types with the conversion specifier `u` looks like

```
SCNuN
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
    uint8_t x;

    scanf( "%" SCNu8, &x );

    printf( "x = %u\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love this site. so to be clear, it was really the scanf("%u", &r); line that was "overwritting" the 'numatoms' location do to scanf being unable to limit to one byte.  'numatoms' is getting set correctly by its scanf() (although should also be fixed), it's the second scanf() that is messing things up.

Comment: @user1160866 The problem is the same with the both calls of scanf. As result the memory around the variables is overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

`uint8_t` is 8 bits long `%u` reads an unsigned int (probably 32 bits long).

You either need to make `numatoms` "bigger" (i.e. `unsigned int`) or read the correct size (see [scanf can't scan into inttypes (uint8_t)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748257/scanf-cant-scan-into-inttypes-uint8-t))