# sscanf seems to behave different on uint variables vs int variables in c

Tags: c, int, scanf, uint

I am developing a microcontroller program and want to read digits from a string into integer variables using `sscanf()`.
The problem is I get a different behavior when using `int` declarations vs `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`.

This is using `int` for variable declaration:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 int main()
 {
     int power;
     int hr;
     int cadence;
     sscanf("204 67 94","%d %d %d",&power, &hr, &cadence);
     printf("power: %d, hr: %d, cadence: %d", power, hr, cadence);        
     return 0;
 }
```

and when put into https://www.onlinegdb.com/ returns:

```
power: 204, hr: 67, cadence: 94

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

This is the way I would expect it to behave.

---

Whereas using `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    uint16_t power;
    uint8_t hr;
    uint16_t cadence;
    sscanf("204 67 94","%d %d %d",&power, &hr, &cadence);
    printf("power: %d, hr: %d, cadence: %d", power, hr, cadence);
    return 0;
}
```

when put into https://www.onlinegdb.com/ delivers an output of:

```
power: 0, hr: 67, cadence: 94

...Program finished with exit code 0
 Press ENTER to exit console.
```

So for some reason power (or more general it seems the first variable) is set to 0.
Could anybody please point me in the right direction and explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The *real* problem here is that you haven't cranked up compiler warnings high enough that it would catch this.

Comment: The _real_ problem is that you have not read the manual page - See [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: The `XXXscanf()` and `XXXprintf()` functions give undefined behaviour if a format specifier does not match the type of the corresponding variable.  `%d` specifies a SIGNED integral type, and supplying an unsigned variable of any size for the corresponding parameter gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format specifier would be

```
scanf("%" SCNu16, &power);
```

Using the wrong format specifier is **Undefined behavior**. You can do the same thing for `sscanf` too.

```
sscanf("204","%"SCNu16 ,&power);
```

Similarly for `uint8_t` it will be `SCNu8`. Similarly for printing you would use the correct one -

```
printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", power);
```

ALso compile your code  with warnings enabled -`gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`. The warnings you see - try to resolve them diligently. That would help you from big problems. Check the manual for `sscanf` to know that they return something - check it, to know whether `sscanf` call is sucessful or not.

Answer (score 5):

In the second example, you're using the wrong formats for the types of the variables.

You should use the macros from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
 SCNu8   --> uint8_t
 SCNu16  --> uint16_t
```

You would probably be safe with `%hhu` for the `uint8_t` and `%hu` for the `uint16_t`.

You get odd behaviour because you lied to your compiler; this is how it gets its own back.  Don't lie to your compiler!

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier requires a pointer to an `int`. If you use `%u`, for an unsigned value, you must use `unsigned int`. You can't use other types like `uint16_t` or `uint8_t`. So do:

```
unsigned int power;
unsigned int hr;
unsigned int cadence;
sscanf("204 67 94","%d %d %d",&power, &hr, &cadence);
```

Comment: How much does the use of `%d` instead of `%u` matter?  It isn't ideal; how serious is it?

Comment: Probably doesn't matter much, but of course `%d` will correctly scan a negative number and put a value in an `unsigned int` that isn't actually negative.

Comment: Hmmm…[C11 7.21.6.2 `fscanf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) says: _`d` — Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
expected for the subject sequence of the `strtol` function with the value 10
for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
signed integer._  The specification for `u` is analogous and specifies 'pointer to unsigned integer'.  Strictly, you're on thin ice.  Practically, maybe not so much.  (And what's with the 'in the absence of a size modifier' part of the specification, I wonder?)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main()
{
    uint16_t power;
    uint8_t hr;
    uint16_t cadence;
    sscanf("204 67 94","%"SCNu16 "%"SCNu8 "%"SCNu16,&power, &hr, &cadence);
    printf("power: %"PRIu16 " hr: %"PRIu8", cadence: %"PRIu16, power, hr, cadence);
    return 0;
}
```

This did it and produces output as expected. 
Further searching led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23748311/9246687 which helped additionally.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You are certainly allowed to answer your own question, but it is not required. If you receive an answer which solved the issue, you should usually [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that answer to indicate that the question has been resolved to your satisfaction. You should also consider upvoting answers you found useful, possibly including the answer you accepted.